# SQL How to effectively use dynamic sql query when output COLUMN order is important

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

My question is really how to ensure that the ORDER of the OUTPUT is maintained when using dynamic query to get data out. I have a couple of dynamic queries that I am utilizing and I notice that when I run the same query on different machines, I get output in different orders. Currently, I store the data outputted into a temp table which assume the order of the output to be the same as that on my local machine but on production, it is all switched up.  How do I get more control of this so that **every time** the query is run, the order of the output is maintained?

When I go to use an Order BY in my dynamic query I get the error

**Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.**

```
 DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

           IF EXISTS
                (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
                            WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#ibutes')
                )
                BEGIN
                            DROP TABLE #ibutes
                END
    Create table #ibutes
    (
                ProductID uniqueIdentifier,
            PAID uniqueidentifier, 
            Label nvarchar(50),
            Val nvarchar(3072),
            unit nvarchar(50) 
    )
    ;With Number
As
(
 Select 1 as rownum union all  Select 2 union all Select 3 union all Select 4 union all Select 5 union all Select 6 union all Select 7 union all Select 8 union all Select 9 union all Select 10 union all Select 11 union all Select 12 union all Select 13 union all Select 14 union all Select 15 union all Select 16 union all Select 17 union all Select 18 union all Select 19 union all Select 20 union all Select 21 
),
ProductDetail 
as 
(
   select P.ProdID, N.rownum from IDWProduct P cross join Number N
)
Insert into #ibutes
Select ProdID ,  PAVibuteID, COALESCE(PANAme,''), COALESCE(PAVValue,''), COALESCE(unitLabel,'') 
 from ProductDetail P
Left join 
(select Pr.*, PAName, row_number() over (partition by PAVProductID order by PAVID) as Rn from IDWProductibuteValues Pr  
inner join IDWibutes  on PAID = PAVibuteID Where PAIscustom = 0 AND PAIsManufacturerSpecific =0 AND PANAME NOT IN 
('Brand Name', 'Standard', 'Application', 'Sub Brand', 'Type', 'Special Features')) 
Pr ON rownum = Pr.Rn And PAVProductID = ProdID  
left join IDWUnitofMeasures on Pr.PAVunit = unitID 

--Select * from #ibutes

   select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from tempdb.sys.columns as C  
         where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#ibutes')  AND  C.name Not in ('ProductID')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

 --select @colsUnpivot

 select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ','  + quotename(c.name   + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by ProductID   order by ProductID) rn  from #ibutes
                    ) t
                     cross apply 
                      tempdb.sys.columns  as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#ibutes')   AND  C.name Not in ('ProductID')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

  --select @colsPivot
  set @query = 'select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select   
           Cast (PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
           ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
           ,Cast (Val as NVarchar(3072)) Val
           ,Cast (unit as NVarchar(3072))  unit  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
          from #ibutes

     ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

The results of running the query

ON MY LOCAL/DEV MACHINE

========================

```
select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select   
       Cast (PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
       ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
           ,Cast (Val as NVarchar(3072)) Val
           ,Cast (unit as NVarchar(3072))  unit  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
          from #ibutes
     ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ([Label],[unit],[Val],[PAID])
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ([Label1],[unit1],[Val1],[PAID1],[Label2],[unit2],[Val2],[PAID2],[Label3],[unit3],[Val3],[PAID3],[Label4],[unit4],[Val4],[PAID4],[Label5],[unit5],[Val5],[PAID5],[Label6],[unit6],[Val6],[PAID6],[Label7],[unit7],[Val7],[PAID7],[Label8],[unit8],[Val8],[PAID8],[Label9],[unit9],[Val9],[PAID9],[Label10],[unit10],[Val10],[PAID10],[Label11],[unit11],[Val11],[PAID11],[Label12],[unit12],[Val12],[PAID12],[Label13],[unit13],[Val13],[PAID13],[Label14],[unit14],[Val14],[PAID14],[Label15],[unit15],[Val15],[PAID15],[Label16],[unit16],[Val16],[PAID16],[Label17],[unit17],[Val17],[PAID17],[Label18],[unit18],[Val18],[PAID18],[Label19],[unit19],[Val19],[PAID19],[Label20],[unit20],[Val20],[PAID20],[Label21],[unit21],[Val21],[PAID21])
      ) p
```

### ON PRODUCTION MACHINE HOWEVER IT IS DIFFERENT. PLEASE NOTICE THE CHANGE IN ORDER OF THE

COLUMNS

```
select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select   
       Cast (PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
       ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
           ,Cast (Val as NVarchar(3072)) Val
           ,Cast (Unit as NVarchar(3072))  Unit  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
          from #ibutes
     ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ([PAID],[Label],[Val],[Unit])
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ([PAID1],[Label1],[Val1],[Unit1],[PAID2],[Label2],[Val2],[Unit2],[PAID3],[Label3],[Val3],[Unit3],[PAID4],[Label4],[Val4],[Unit4],[PAID5],[Label5],[Val5],[Unit5],[PAID6],[Label6],[Val6],[Unit6],[PAID7],[Label7],[Val7],[Unit7],[PAID8],[Label8],[Val8],[Unit8],[PAID9],[Label9],[Val9],[Unit9],[PAID10],[Label10],[Val10],[Unit10],[PAID11],[Label11],[Val11],[Unit11],[PAID12],[Label12],[Val12],[Unit12],[PAID13],[Label13],[Val13],[Unit13],[PAID14],[Label14],[Val14],[Unit14],[PAID15],[Label15],[Val15],[Unit15],[PAID16],[Label16],[Val16],[Unit16],[PAID17],[Label17],[Val17],[Unit17],[PAID18],[Label18],[Val18],[Unit18],[PAID19],[Label19],[Val19],[Unit19],[PAID20],[Label20],[Val20],[Unit20],[PAID21],[Label21],[Val21],[Unit21])
      ) p
```

Please note the difference btw local machine where the order seems alphabetical

**[Label1],[unit1],[Val1],[PAID1],[Label2],[unit2].**
 . . .

while on Production machine, it is not

**[PAID1],[Label1],[Val1],[Unit1],[PAID2],[Label2],[Val2],[Unit2], .. .  .  .**

Comment: I think best way to explicitly sort your data

Comment: How do I explicitly sort my data please?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Where did you try placing the ORDER BY?

Comment: right After the FROM #ibutes statement?

Comment: It's hard to read such a massive query, but you can use "select top 100 percent" and than use order by.

Comment: The important part of the query is really the dynamic part at the bottom, where I select 5 fields to return on. How do I execute a dynamic query and select top 100 or order the data in anyway?

Comment: you can also put data from #TEMPTABL to another temporary table #TEMPTABL2, and use sorting and this step.
You may also consider to redesign your code and avoid insert into from stored procedure.

Comment: How do I order data that i am not sure of the order to begin with? I am blindly pulling the data from the dynamic query into a temptable already(since the data is not always in the order my temptable defines). I would really like to get more control over that process please and I don't know how to.

Comment: Is it the order the returned rows that us different or is it the order of the columns in the resultset?

Comment: Order of the columns in the recordset

Comment: Add `c.name` to the order by clause in the query that builds `@colsPivot` so it becomes  `order by t.rn, c.name`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one only obvious answer. Use the `order by` clause in the dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, all queries whether dynamic or not are not guaranteed to come out the same on different machines!
If the order of the results is important to you, use `ORDER BY`

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME
```

Comment: I would do this if I could do a select from a dynamic query in that way. But in what I have, I call the stored proc that executes the dynamic query with an insert into a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want order then use an order by.
In absence of an order by there is no guaranteed order.
If there is a tie then no guarantee the sort will repeat on the tie.
Use enough columns there is no tie.

It appears you are referring to order of the columns not rows.

If you select * you will the the columns in the order they are defined in the table.
If you need to control the order of the columns then don't use *.

```
select table1.col4, table1.col2 
from table1
```

Comment: use an order by where? When I run the INSERT  INTO  #TEMPTABL 
EXECUTE  StoredProcThatContainsTheDynamicQuery?

Comment: @ypercube Yes I have been following and I made a comment.  OR versus AND in the where makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
'select *
  from
  (
    select ProductID,
        col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
        val
    from 
    (
      select top 100 percent
       Cast (PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
       ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
       ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
       ,Cast (Val as NVarchar(3072)) Val
       ,Cast (unit as NVarchar(3072))  unit  
        ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
      from #ibutes
      order by row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) asc
 ) x
    unpivot
    (
      val
      for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
    ) u
  ) x1
  pivot
  (
    max(val)
    for new_col in
      ('+ @colspivot +')
  ) p'
```

Comment: while the code above works, it is not really what I am looking for. I need to order the columns so they appear in the exact order every time. With the above, I still have the same problem which is different column order on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we know where you're adding the ORDER BY, the answer is clearer.
You're trying to order the query whose results are inserted into @colsPivot and that's the problem.

ORDER BY is mainly used for ordering the final results and thus should be on the final query (the dynamic one).
The exception to this is if it is used as part of a "limiting" query (eg. TOP 10).

Try adding the ORDER BY to the dynamic query and let us know if it worked.

Comment: Where in the dynamic query do I add the order by statement? If I add it right after the **from #ibutes** in the dynamic query, I get the error message I posted above.

Comment: The dynamic query is the variable you run with 'EXEC'. In this case @query.

Comment: I added that on my machine but that did not seem to fix it on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

why not change the following:

```
set @query = 'select *
      from
```

to something like

```
set @query = 'select *
      into #x
      from
```

you'll need to explicitly create `#x` before the dynamic sql i.e

```
create table #x
(
blah int,
blah char(8)
)
```

then after the `exec` statement have a further query

```
select *
from #x
order by whatever
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but in what ORDER will the columns be defined in #x to ensure that no matter what machine this query is run on, the columns will be returned in the right order? I am having this problem right now and I am looking for help on maybe possible commands that will ensure it is CONSISTENT no matter how many times or what machine it is run on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

Add the order by below to the first query

```
select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
     from tempdb.sys.columns as C  
     where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#ibutes')  AND  C.name Not in ('ProductID')

ORDER BY c.column_id --Add this

     for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

change the order by below of the second query

```
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ','  + quotename(c.name   + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                from
                (
                  select row_number() over(partition by ProductID   order by ProductID) rn  from #ibutes
                ) t
                 cross apply 
                  tempdb.sys.columns  as C
               where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#ibutes')   AND  C.name Not in ('ProductID')
               group by c.name, t.rn

               ORDER BY c.column_id --Change this

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Hope that helps...